# Slow SQL Query with many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am a kind new born in `SQL` issues, and i really appreciate yours helps. I got a query (not written by me) and it is taking almost 15 min to run with 550 000 lines, so i would like to improve it , but i can not see how .

Follow query, i've tried to filter with only 2021 data but it doesn't work...

Tks all for support!! Best wishes!

```
Select 
    
    d.*, --BD dbo.Documents (23 496 430)
    case when d.DateStartStaging >0 then d.DateStartStaging else d.DateArchived end as CreatedDate,
    year(DateArchived) as Year,
    month(DateArchived) as Month,
    cast(DateArchived as date) as DateArchivedAux
From (select distinct  
        
        c.Name as InvestorName,
        dc.ClientId,
        lp.Judicialfile,
        d.id as DocumentId, 
        lkp.Name + isnull('/'+lk2.name,'') as DocumentType,
        lkp.Name AS DocumentName, 
        lk2.Name AS DocumentSubCode, 
        lda.Description AS ArchiveStatusCodeName, 
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then isnull(uc.DelegatorDisplayName,uc.DisplayName) else isnull(ud.DelegatorDisplayName,ud.DisplayName) end as Nome,
        di.CreatedDate as DocumentDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then h.StatusDate else null end as DateStartStaging,
        h.ActivityDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then he.StatusDate else h.StatusDate end as DateArchived
        
from HST_Documents h with (NOLOCK)
    inner join vwSessions       as ud with (NOLOCK) on h.SessionId = ud.Id 
    left join  HST_Documents    as he with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = he.DocumentId and he.StatusDate >= h.StatusDate   and (he.PreviousArchiveStatusCode = '0' and he.ArchiveStatusCode = '1') and he.IsActive=1
    inner join Documents        as d with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = d.Id and d.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lkp with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentCode = lkp.Code and lkp.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lk2 with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentSubCode = lk2.Code and lk2.IsActive=1
    left join  DocumentsClients as dc with (NOLOCK) on d.id = dc.DocId 
    left join  vwContacts       as c with (NOLOCK) on d.InvestorId = c.Id
    left join  vwSessions       as uc with (NOLOCK) on he.SessionId = uc.Id 
    left  join (select 
                llp.LegalProcessId,
                lp.JudicialFile,
                c.InvestorId
                from LegalProcesses AS lp WITH(NOLOCK)
                 Inner Join dbo.LoanLegalProcesses AS llp WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LegalProcessId = lp.Id  and llp.isactive=1
                 Inner Join dbo.Loans AS l WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LoanId = l.Id
                 Inner Join dbo.Clients AS c WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.ClientId = c.Id 
                 where  lp.isactive=1
                ) as lp on lp.LegalProcessId = d.LegalProcessId and lp.InvestorId=d.investorid
    left join  LKP_DocumentArchiveStatus as lda WITH (NOLOCK) ON h.ArchiveStatusCode = lda.Code 
    left join  DocumentInfo di WITH(NOLOCK) ON h.DocumentId=di.id
where   (he.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01' or h.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01') 
        and h.IsActive = 1 
        and ((h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' AND ISNULL(h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode,'-') <> '0') or (h.ArchiveStatusCode = '1' 
        and h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode is null)) 
) as d
where d.ActivityDate >= '2021-01-01' -- filtro de data 2021
and DocumentName in ('AM DOC' ,'BORROWER DOC' ,'LEGAL DOC' , 'ARQUIVO','Notificação' ,'Requerimento') 
and Nome in (   'Ligia Pacheco',
                'Margarida Silva',
                'Claudia Matos',
                'Silvia Pinto',
                'Vanessa Carvalho',
                'Nidea Pires',
                'Ana Cristina Louro',
                'Soraia Frias',
                'Maria Isabel Eusebio',
                'Ines Melo',
                'Sergio Xavier',
                'Natacha Natu',
                'Sandra Goncalves',
                'Mariana Silva',
                'Andreia Filipa Paiva') --filtro por users
```

Comment: Spamming your code with NOLOCK is an extremely bad idea.  Please also generate an execution plan for that query, and share it using this website or similar: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  *(Edit your question and add the link to your plan there.)*

Comment: Tks @MatBailie, but i dont have access (it is not available in my MSSMS, it is not allowed to my user profile). Is there any other way to help me?

Comment: you can add some  options to add statistics and  SHOWPLAN before your query
```SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;
```

Comment: hi @ThiagoBellas i think you should at least try to format th SQL code better and provide a few of the involved tables schemas, so that we can understand better the problem here

Comment: Tks @Tohm, i've tried the three options and i've got this. (I will cutoff in part just because the characters limit)
(562248 rows affected)
Table 'LKP_ContactTypes'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'Contact'. Scan count 31, logical reads 9065, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LKP_Documents'. Scan count 10, logical reads 138, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'HST_Documents'. Scan count 10, logical reads 416662, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Users'. Scan count 20, logical reads 424, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Sessions'. Scan count 10, logical reads 324990, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 23520, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Documents'. Scan count 5, logical reads 208594, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'DocumentsClients'. Scan count 5, logical reads 41310, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'DocumentInfo'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3099945, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LKP_DocumentArchiveStatus'. Scan count 4, logical reads 2066634, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Clients'. Scan count 2926064, logical reads 8790055, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'Loans'. Scan count 2926064, logical reads 8785786, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LoanLegalProcesses'. Scan count 550259, logical reads 1657975, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Table 'LegalProcesses'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1651938, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 829 ms, elapsed time = 861 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(562533 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 75076 ms,  elapsed time = 492333 ms.

Completion time: 2021-10-14T11:40:49.9292913+01:00

Comment: Please ***DO NOT*** add these as comments.  ***EDIT*** your question, and post the information there, as formatted text.

Comment: @MatBailie sorry, i am new here, i am learning, i will do exacly how you recommend. tks

Comment: Please share a query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. Please also add table and index definitions to your question (not as comments). Without this, this is not really answerable

Comment: `distinct` can be slow. Chucking `distinct` at a query usuallly indicates poorly thought out joins. Look through your joins and work out why you are getting duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick modification to improve performance is to move filter in subquery.

Distinct operation is very performance-intensive.
In your case the Distinct is launched before the second where.

(First where -> distinct -> second where)

an example by combining the two conditions **where**:

```
Select 
    
    d.*, --BD dbo.Documents (23 496 430)
    case when d.DateStartStaging >0 then d.DateStartStaging else d.DateArchived end as CreatedDate,
    year(DateArchived) as Year,
    month(DateArchived) as Month,
    cast(DateArchived as date) as DateArchivedAux
From (select distinct  
        
        c.Name as InvestorName,
        dc.ClientId,
        lp.Judicialfile,
        d.id as DocumentId, 
        lkp.Name + isnull('/'+lk2.name,'') as DocumentType,
        lkp.Name AS DocumentName, 
        lk2.Name AS DocumentSubCode, 
        lda.Description AS ArchiveStatusCodeName, 
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then isnull(uc.DelegatorDisplayName,uc.DisplayName) else isnull(ud.DelegatorDisplayName,ud.DisplayName) end as Nome,
        di.CreatedDate as DocumentDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then h.StatusDate else null end as DateStartStaging,
        h.ActivityDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then he.StatusDate else h.StatusDate end as DateArchived
        
from HST_Documents h with (NOLOCK)
    inner join vwSessions       as ud with (NOLOCK) on h.SessionId = ud.Id 
    left join  HST_Documents    as he with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = he.DocumentId and he.StatusDate >= h.StatusDate   and (he.PreviousArchiveStatusCode = '0' and he.ArchiveStatusCode = '1') and he.IsActive=1
    inner join Documents        as d with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = d.Id and d.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lkp with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentCode = lkp.Code and lkp.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lk2 with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentSubCode = lk2.Code and lk2.IsActive=1
    left join  DocumentsClients as dc with (NOLOCK) on d.id = dc.DocId 
    left join  vwContacts       as c with (NOLOCK) on d.InvestorId = c.Id
    left join  vwSessions       as uc with (NOLOCK) on he.SessionId = uc.Id 
    left  join (select 
                llp.LegalProcessId,
                lp.JudicialFile,
                c.InvestorId
                from LegalProcesses AS lp WITH(NOLOCK)
                 Inner Join dbo.LoanLegalProcesses AS llp WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LegalProcessId = lp.Id  and llp.isactive=1
                 Inner Join dbo.Loans AS l WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LoanId = l.Id
                 Inner Join dbo.Clients AS c WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.ClientId = c.Id 
                 where  lp.isactive=1
                ) as lp on lp.LegalProcessId = d.LegalProcessId and lp.InvestorId=d.investorid
    left join  LKP_DocumentArchiveStatus as lda WITH (NOLOCK) ON h.ArchiveStatusCode = lda.Code 
    left join  DocumentInfo di WITH(NOLOCK) ON h.DocumentId=di.id
where   (he.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01' or h.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01') 
        and h.IsActive = 1 
        and ((h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' AND ISNULL(h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode,'-') <> '0') or (h.ArchiveStatusCode = '1' 
        and h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode is null)) 
        
        and h.ActivityDate  >= '2021-01-01' -- filtro de data 2021
        and lkp.Name in ('AM DOC' ,'BORROWER DOC' ,'LEGAL DOC' , 'ARQUIVO','Notificação' ,'Requerimento') 
        and ((h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' and  isnull(uc.DelegatorDisplayName,uc.DisplayName)in (   'Ligia Pacheco',
                'Margarida Silva',
                'Claudia Matos',
                'Silvia Pinto',
                'Vanessa Carvalho',
                'Nidea Pires',
                'Ana Cristina Louro',
                'Soraia Frias',
                'Maria Isabel Eusebio',
                'Ines Melo',
                'Sergio Xavier',
                'Natacha Natu',
                'Sandra Goncalves',
                'Mariana Silva',
                'Andreia Filipa Paiva')) 
            OR (h.ArchiveStatusCode != '0' and  isnull(ud.DelegatorDisplayName,ud.DisplayName)in (   'Ligia Pacheco',
                'Margarida Silva',
                'Claudia Matos',
                'Silvia Pinto',
                'Vanessa Carvalho',
                'Nidea Pires',
                'Ana Cristina Louro',
                'Soraia Frias',
                'Maria Isabel Eusebio',
                'Ines Melo',
                'Sergio Xavier',
                'Natacha Natu',
                'Sandra Goncalves',
                'Mariana Silva',
                'Andreia Filipa Paiva')))  
) as d
```

You can also apply distinct after second where condition.

an example by launching **distinct** after the two conditions **where**:

```
Select distinct
    
    d.*, --BD dbo.Documents (23 496 430)
    case when d.DateStartStaging >0 then d.DateStartStaging else d.DateArchived end as CreatedDate,
    year(DateArchived) as Year,
    month(DateArchived) as Month,
    cast(DateArchived as date) as DateArchivedAux
From (select           
        c.Name as InvestorName,
        dc.ClientId,
        lp.Judicialfile,
        d.id as DocumentId, 
        lkp.Name + isnull('/'+lk2.name,'') as DocumentType,
        lkp.Name AS DocumentName, 
        lk2.Name AS DocumentSubCode, 
        lda.Description AS ArchiveStatusCodeName, 
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then isnull(uc.DelegatorDisplayName,uc.DisplayName) else isnull(ud.DelegatorDisplayName,ud.DisplayName) end as Nome,
        di.CreatedDate as DocumentDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then h.StatusDate else null end as DateStartStaging,
        h.ActivityDate,
        case when h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' then he.StatusDate else h.StatusDate end as DateArchived
        
from HST_Documents h with (NOLOCK)
    inner join vwSessions       as ud with (NOLOCK) on h.SessionId = ud.Id 
    left join  HST_Documents    as he with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = he.DocumentId and he.StatusDate >= h.StatusDate   and (he.PreviousArchiveStatusCode = '0' and he.ArchiveStatusCode = '1') and he.IsActive=1
    inner join Documents        as d with (NOLOCK) on h.DocumentId = d.Id and d.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lkp with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentCode = lkp.Code and lkp.IsActive=1
    left join  LKP_Documents    as lk2 with (NOLOCK) on d.DocumentSubCode = lk2.Code and lk2.IsActive=1
    left join  DocumentsClients as dc with (NOLOCK) on d.id = dc.DocId 
    left join  vwContacts       as c with (NOLOCK) on d.InvestorId = c.Id
    left join  vwSessions       as uc with (NOLOCK) on he.SessionId = uc.Id 
    left  join (select 
                llp.LegalProcessId,
                lp.JudicialFile,
                c.InvestorId
                from LegalProcesses AS lp WITH(NOLOCK)
                 Inner Join dbo.LoanLegalProcesses AS llp WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LegalProcessId = lp.Id  and llp.isactive=1
                 Inner Join dbo.Loans AS l WITH(NOLOCK) ON llp.LoanId = l.Id
                 Inner Join dbo.Clients AS c WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.ClientId = c.Id 
                 where  lp.isactive=1
                ) as lp on lp.LegalProcessId = d.LegalProcessId and lp.InvestorId=d.investorid
    left join  LKP_DocumentArchiveStatus as lda WITH (NOLOCK) ON h.ArchiveStatusCode = lda.Code 
    left join  DocumentInfo di WITH(NOLOCK) ON h.DocumentId=di.id
where   (he.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01' or h.StatusDate >= '2021-01-01') 
        and h.IsActive = 1 
        and ((h.ArchiveStatusCode = '0' AND ISNULL(h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode,'-') <> '0') or (h.ArchiveStatusCode = '1' 
        and h.PreviousArchiveStatusCode is null)) 
) as d
where d.ActivityDate >= '2021-01-01' -- filtro de data 2021
and DocumentName in ('AM DOC' ,'BORROWER DOC' ,'LEGAL DOC' , 'ARQUIVO','Notificação' ,'Requerimento') 
and Nome in (   'Ligia Pacheco',
                'Margarida Silva',
                'Claudia Matos',
                'Silvia Pinto',
                'Vanessa Carvalho',
                'Nidea Pires',
                'Ana Cristina Louro',
                'Soraia Frias',
                'Maria Isabel Eusebio',
                'Ines Melo',
                'Sergio Xavier',
                'Natacha Natu',
                'Sandra Goncalves',
                'Mariana Silva',
                'Andreia Filipa Paiva') --filtro por users
```

you can also avoid to use `with (NOLOCK)` for each tables by defining the transaction level (before your query)

```
set transaction level read uncommitted
```

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.